Constructing an nth-degree polynomial that is "sinusoid-like" within a finite range?
What I need to be able to do is construct a polynomial that behaves similarly to (but not exactly like) a periodic sinusoidal function only within a finite domain.
I am not sure if this is an interpolation problem, or if there is a pattern that can be followed to generate coefficients.
To clarify, I am not asking about the polynomial approximations for trig functions like sine and cosine. The values that this function produces are only important at integer multiples of 1 and $\frac{1}{2}$.
More precisely,
Given an inclusive domain $[a, b]$ (where both $a$ and $b$ are integers and $a < b$ ), construct a polynomial function $f(x)$ such that:

$f(a)$ = $f(b)$ = 1
$f(x)$ yields 1 for all integer values of $x$ within $[a, b]$
$f(x)$ yields 0 (i.e., has a root) at all $x$ that are integer multiples of $\frac{1}{2}$ within $[a, b]$
$f(x)$ yields values between 0 and 1 (non-inclusive) for all $x$ in $[a, b]$ that are not integers or integer multiples of $\frac{1}{2}$.
all y-values of $f(x)$ fall within the range $[0, 1]$ within the x-range $[a, b]$

The behavior of $f(x)$ is undefined outside of $[a, b]$ and therefore is not subject to any constraints.
A small example is this function $f(x)$ which would satisfy the criteria within the x-interval $[0, 1]$
$f(x) = 16x^{6}-48x^{5}+36x^{4}+8x^{3}-12x^{2}+1$

This function I adapted from here.
However, I am not sure how these coefficients were generated originally. I essentially want to create a general method for constructing polynomials like this one, for any arbitrary range where oscillation is desired.
I am familiar with Lagrange interpolation, but this could be quite a slow process if $b - a$ is substantially large. I am wondering if there is a faster way to derive the coefficients of the polynomial given the constraints mentioned above.

With $n+1$ « free » constraints you need a degree $n$ polynomial so any interpolation will have the same complexity. Although you could have some luck for very particular cases

Also there is a generalised method that interpolates points and derivatives at these points, combining taylor and Lagrange, which can be helpful for your local maxima and minima
